# Accessing NSMutableArray from different class in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

Does anyone can explain me why my NSMutableArray is empty when I'm trying to access to it from another class?

**MasterViewController**

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    var mutOb:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var test: String = "test"
        self.mutOb.insertObject(test, atIndex: self.mutOb.count)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(self.mutOb)
        // RESULT ( test )
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var masterViewController: MasterViewController = MasterViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(self.masterViewController.mutOb)

        // RESULT ( )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of MasterViewController, not referring back to the existing instance.  See the attached link for information about passing data between controllers:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Do you have any other link that can me explain this for swift?

Comment: I can't find any examples in swift. Only using segues to pass variables but I don't want to use segue for this.

Comment: Sorry, only google...  It looks like you are using a Master/Detail application - if that's based on Apple's template, try looking at AppDelegate.swift to see how you might get a reference to the MasterViewController.